# How to be FIDO Compliant with existing registration / login functionality

Tags: fido-u2f, fido, webauthn

I have existing website with Registration & Login functionality. I want to make this process FIDO Compliant with implementation of UAF / U2F and later FIDO2. Unfortunately couldn't find step by step series of tutorials.I want to implement this using PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Good starting point for WebAuthn is mdn, you get the basic idea of how it works
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API

and then you can just follow webAuthn specification to implement relying party operations (7) on a server.
https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/
and use the APIs on a client described in 5.1.3 registration and 5.1.4 authentication

and also there is an example RP implementation provided by google, thought its in java
https://github.com/google/webauthndemo

other great source of information for FIDO protocols generally is the yubico website, they even have a php library which might simplify things for you
https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/Libraries/List_of_libraries.html